# How should I deal with error:-- unbalanced parenthesis at position 32

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

CODE:- train_validation_split = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit([6, 4])

```
   (train_data, validation_data), test_data = tfds.load(
   name="imdb_reviews", 
   split=(train_validation_split, tfds.Split.TEST),
   as_supervised=True)
```

1). ERROR = unbalanced parenthesis at position 32.

2). I am getting this error while loading the imdb dataset.

3). 
[Image of Code with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niPas.jpg)

Comment: Please provide more information. Give a link of the dataset, provide the code that you have tried and the exact error message. Python never gives error in the format you have mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tldr;

- It's the Windows path separator problem. (Why do Windows do that? Read more about [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/))
- Resolution:

  - Use [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) to use `tensorflow_datasets` (Recommended)
  - Use *nix-like systems (where path separator is `/`)

### What went wrong?

*Escape character* and *regex*

At *line 156* from `what_ever_python/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets/text/imdb.py`

```py
reg_path = "(?P<label>neg|pos)" if labeled else "unsup"
reg = re.compile(os.path.join("^%s" % directory, reg_path, ""))
```

- On Windows

  1. `os.path.join("^%s" % directory, reg_path, "")` => `'^aclImdb\\train\\(?P<label>neg|pos)\\'`
  2. And this is what the program see `'^aclImdb\train\(?P<label>neg|pos)\'`
  3. And the regex see: `^` + `aclImdb` + **tab** + `rain` + `(` (this the escaped character which led to the error `unbalanced parenthesis`) + `...` + **)** (this is a close-group character which its open companion has been *escaped*) + `...`
- On *nix

  1. `os.path.join("^%s" % directory, reg_path, "")` => `'^aclImdb/train/(?P<label>neg|pos)/'` and nothing is being *escaped*.

Comment: Thank you for the post. I had the same issue and this put some light on it. For me, I added "if (platform.system()=='Windows'):   comp_path = comp_path.replace('\\', '\\\\')" to the imdb.py file.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this post late, but it looks like you're following [one of the Tensorflow Beta tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/basic_text_classification_with_tfhub).

Per shioko's answer, there is a bug in the `tensorflow_datasets` library's handling of Windows path separators, in particular as it's done in the `imdb.py` dataset loader. I will point out, however, that this is not a problem with `os.path.join()` per se , and no blame should be shifted that way. That function needn't be maligned since it is, as they say, *just doing its job*. My recommendation is to keep using your current dev environment (especially if you own a powerful GPU!) but fix the bug in `tensorflow_datasets` per instructions below.

The real problem is in the interaction between Windows path separators and regular expressions, which treat those separators as escape sequences. A bit of a mouthful, but the basic advice here is as follows: **in order to stop treating an escape sequence as an escape sequence, you have to escape the escape sequence**. The backslash is a common escape sequence, so it's become something of a victim of its own popularity. Sometimes it has to be escaped. Sometimes it has to be escaped a lot. Sometimes it has to be escaped `"^file:\\\\\\\\c:\\\\foo\\\\bar\\\\baz.txt$"` levels of a lot.

Therefore, the solution I recommend to the tensorflow_datasets maintainers (or people willing to patch [`tensorflow_datasets/text/imdb.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/master/tensorflow_datasets/text/imdb.py) themselves) is to pass the path separator through `re.escape()` before calling join, using code that looks something like the following:

```
reg = re.compile(re.escape(os.path.sep).join(["^%s" % re.escape(directory), reg_path, ""]))
```

That should replace the statement starting with `reg =` around lines 159/160 of imdb.py. I'm not using `os.path.join()` because it's not perfectly suited to this problem, but I am using its brethren, `os.path.sep`. I'm also not writing off `os.path.join()` entirely since there's still a lot of things it's good at, like joining path components in non-regex related scenarios.

Note that I'm also `re.escape()`ing the source directory. That is useful for avoiding a whole other class of bugs where elements of the path name are treated, for example, as wildcards. I'll probably just submit this change as a pull request to the tensorflow_datasets library, which should hopefully save other ML enthusiasts following Tensorflow's official tutorials on Windows machines (such as myself) from having to manually apply patches to the contrib libraries they rely on.